# Is there any way to make R Shiny support multiple users? I'm talking about hundreds of concurrent users

Tags: r, shiny

Is there any way to make R Shiny support multiple users? I'm talking about hundreds of concurrent users.
To add some context: I'm not talking about Authentication (username / password). That will be taken care of by Auth0 (see auth0.com). So AFTER they are logged in, I see that Shiny Server does not pass the username to the Shiny session (maybe deliberately, so that you are forced to purchase the Commercial license to Shiny Server?).My question is more about : a) how do I make it recognize the username of the logged in user? b) will it scale to hundreds of concurrent (simultaneous) users?

Comment: The free version of Shiny Server Open Source does not support multiple `R` processes simultaneously, that is with Shiny Server Pro. I think there is no way other than using Shiny Server Pro or using a free version of Shiny Server Pro (for teaching purpose only).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.shinyproxy.io/ attempts to solve problem b): it spawns a Docker container per application and per user. It should scale well if you give it enough resources (unfortunately it's difficult to estimate what "enough" is beforehand... You should run your own tests).

I'm not sure about problem a) but Shinyproxy deals well with authentication of users.

Comment: Is one Shiny Session = 1 R process (on the Linux server)? So if there are 20 concurrent users with 20 Shiny Sessions, are they all still talking to the same R process? (I think so from a quick experiment where I opened the same app from 2 computers, but I just want to confirm).

What if I have 50 users and 50 corresponding Shiny apps (or one Shiny app with 50 files such as index_userA.Rmd, index_userB.Rmd, etc;) I suppose 50 R processes will be launched on the server?

Comment: In Shinyproxy, no. There is one container per user/application, with a dedicated R process inside each. In the very pessimistic scenario of 50 users on 50 apps, there would be 2500 processes, each in its own container. Again, I have no idea of the resource impact. I also don't know about administration of Shinyproxy and how to handle automatic closing of hanging sessions. But in a more realistic scenario, I'd expect it to be sustainable. I have no direct experience of using it in production, but I've heard of people doing it successfully.

Comment: Regarding problem b): ShinyProxy now also allows to use a Kubernetes back-end for running Shiny apps at datacenter scale. Problem a) is definitely solved as well: user names and group membership of authenticated users are made available to the Shiny app via environment variables - see https://www.shinyproxy.io/configuration/#ldap

Answer (score 0):

The free version of Shiny Server can be enabled to utilize authentication before loading an app (a login screen) but does not then launch the shiny app as the user. This feature is only available in the pro version.

These cases are impossible with free Shiny Server

- User logs in and the app executes a query against a secured database using the logged in identity
- User logs in and the app recognizes them - free Shiny Server is already running under a user account and all users share that space.
- User logs in and has their own private execution environment (if you have thousands of concurrent users you may well run into variable collisions which could expose what another user is looking at)

Comment: Is one Shiny Session = 1 R process (on the Linux server)? So if there are 20 concurrent users with 20 Shiny Sessions, are they all still talking to the same R process? (I think so from a quick experiment where I opened the same app from 2 computers, but I just want to confirm). What if I have 50 users and 50 corresponding Shiny apps (or one Shiny app with 50 files such as index_userA.Rmd, index_userB.Rmd, etc;) I suppose 50 R processes will be launched on the server?

Comment: If you have 20 concurrent users on one app, they're all in the same process (and you have risk of variables let collisions). If you have 20 concurrent users in 20 different apps, they'll be in the same process, but you shouldn't have variable collision issues because shiny does some stuff in the background with different apps.

Answer (score 0):

With the Shiny-Pro you can enable Authentification. The server then gives the App information about username over the variable `session$user`.

In the basic version Shiny-Pro can handle 20 Concurrent users but you can buy an extension so that it can handle up to 120 - 150 concurrent Users.

Comment: Is one Shiny Session = 1 R process (on the Linux server)? So if there are 20 concurrent users with 20 Shiny Sessions, are they all still talking to the same R process? (I think so from a quick experiment where I opened the same app from 2 computers, but I just want to confirm). What if I have 50 users and 50 corresponding Shiny apps (or one Shiny app with 50 files such as index_userA.Rmd, index_userB.Rmd, etc;) I suppose 50 R processes will be launched on the server?

Comment: No the user's share r-processes. The exact number of users who share one process is defined in the server configurations. For the user's is this noticeable in that they all share the data that is defined in the global file. Everything else is individual for each user.